# netem how to do delay for 2-3seconds of all packets for 50-300ms once in 3-10 minutes

Tags: traffic

I'm using netem to do traffic delays. For my testing it is required to perform slightly odd delays. I need introduce a delay 50-300ms to all packets TCP/UDP for 2-3 seconds once in 3-10 minutes. I.e. once delay has happened next delay should happen in 3-10 minutes.

Can I do that just using netem without using additional scripts?

If not, what's the closest achievable?

Answer (score 0):

You can pick random values in `bash`, and map them onto your desired range, using `$RANDOM`. You can run the command "for a while" with `timeout`. Read `man bash timeout`.